# Deserializar JSON JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tengo un `JSON`que es de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El mismo se guarda en un arreglo de JSON,he tratado de deserializarlo de muchas formas pero siempre es `undefined`, he intentado

```
 for (var i = 0; i < ArregloDatos.length; i++) {
            console.log(ArregloDatos[i][0]);
            console.log(ArregloDatos[i].d.nombre);
            console.log(ArregloDatos[i]["nombre"]);
        }
```

Cual es la forma correcta de poder mostrar nombre o apellido, etc?

Comment: `console.log(ArregloDatos.d[0].nombre);`

Comment: @alanfcm me da  `undefined` si por aquello solo intento `xxx.d[0]` solo me imprime el `[`

Comment: Creo que `d` es un string.  Intenta `var d = JSON.parse(ArregloDatos.d); console.log(d[0].nombre);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el método object puedes crear una matriz y acceder a los datos mediante subíndices.

```
const json = {
  "personas": [
    { "Nombre": "Cristobal", "Apellidos": "Colon" },
    { "Nombre": "Pedro", "Apellidos": "Almodovar" }
  ]
}

const personas = Object.values(json)
const persona1 = personas[0][0]
const persona2 = personas[0][1]

console.log(persona1.Nombre)

// Para recorrerlo
personas.forEach(e => {
  for (const i of e) {
   console.log(i)
  }
})

// Otra alternativa sin tener que convertir el objeto a array
for (const i of json.personas) {
 console.log(i.Nombre)
}
```

Comment: La pregunta del OP es sobre **convertir** el JSON a un objeto/array. Además, no es necesario usar `Object.values` para acceder a una propiedad.

Comment: Ya sé que no hace falta convertir el objeto a array y se debe trabajar directamente sobre el array del objeto (Si no es necesario otras cosas) es una alternativa.

Comment: Las alternativas deben ser **necesarias**; en otro caso es un procedimiento que no tiene caso. Te puedes ahorrar los insignificantes ms que toma `Object.values`. Es una alternativa ;).